# Pomegranate wine colour?

Tags: wine, color

The pictures of pomegranate wine I have seen on the internet seem like very dark red wine. The one I made however looked like a milkish pink.
What can account for the difference? How can I control the colour, get rid of the milky look and darken the wine?

**update**
Below is a pic of before and after fermentation. I think I can manage removing the milky aspect of the wine by using pectin enzyme. Running tests now.
However there’s still a significant loss of color. I’d like a nice ruby red and not a twilight pink.

[image: must vs wine]

Comment: Given time, the solids in the wine will drop out and it won't appear milky any more. It will also appear darker as there's less light being reflected. You can speed the process by adding finings.

Comment: My wine had sat for almost 5 months and still it was milky. Can you tell me more about finings? Any link?

Comment: There's a good primer at [Winemaker Magazine](http://winemakermag.com/26-a-clearer-understanding-of-fining-agents)

Comment: Maybe you should edit a proper answer? I think you did answer my question.

Comment: My suspicion is that a "milky pink" wine will never be dark red, even after clarification. You might hope for dark pink or light red. So, I don't think I've answered the question about how to make a dark, red pomegranate wine.

Comment: Right okay. But should pomegranate wine have this colour? Does the pink colour means I did something wrong?

Comment: @Benjamin: Maybe it depends on the pomegranates that you used? If the finished product tastes OK, I wouldn't worry so much about the colour.

Comment: Did you use only pomegranate juice, or was it mixed with something else?

Comment: Different yeast strains can also affect color retention. For example, this page notes a couple common wine yeasts that have decent color retention (search "color" on the page): http://www.brsquared.org/wine/CalcInfo/yeasts.htm

Comment: @Benjamin You should post pictures. It will help figure out the problem more easily. Its hard to know what you mean by "milky" for example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the size difference of the container(s) the pictured?

Homebrew will appear lighter in a smaller container and darker if shown in a large container.

For example, a 3 gallon carboy and a 10 gallon carboy will look completely different even when they're filled with the same liquid.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you either need more pomegranate or perhaps more of the colour has come out as part of the fining process.

What finings have you used? As some fining are harsher than others and are able to take some of the colour out of a wine.

Perhaps next time you might want to add some red grape concentrate or perhaps some beetroot juice (not from concentrate). Perhaps you already have but just a suggestion without seeing your recipe.

Main thing is does it taste nice?

Comment: It tasted amazing!

Comment: In which case I wouldnt worry about the colour so much. Although perhaps next time use more pomegranate or red grape concentrate

Comment: @TheRozza - there are a lot of questions in this answer - these are best asked in the comments under the question so you can then better formulate your answer.

Comment: Sorry, im new to this. I realised this afterwards, as i wasn't sure how to do these types of comments before.

Comment: Can you include a definition of finings?

Answer (score -3):

When making beer, boiling the extract can give the beer a darker flavor. I'm not sure if that would help during mead-making but if there is any boiling involved you could give it a whirl.